# Перестановка элементов массива с XORом индексов

Tags: c, перестановка

В своей программе пользуюсь файлами данных другой; файл данных в целом представляет собой массив, в котором перед сохранением переставляются элементы путём использования XOR индекса массива и случайного 8-битного числа (т.е, если, например, выпало число 117, меняются местами элементы с индексами 0 и 117, 1 и 116 и т.д.; 256 и 373, 257 и 372 и т.д., и т.д. и т.д.). Соответственно, чтобы восстановить исходный порядок чисел в массиве, нужно опять переставить элементы, используя XOR индекса массива и этого числа.
Сейчас файл вычитывается по 512 байт и задача решается в лоб - данные вычитываются во временный буфер, затем копируются в основной с учётом перестановки, условно что-то вроде такого:

```
uint8_t main_buffer[512];
uint8_t temp_buffer[512];
uint8_t cryptor;

cryptor = readCryptor();

while(readNext512Bytes(temp_buffer))
{
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
        main_buffer[i] = temp_buffer[i ^ cryptor]
    }
}
```

Потом появилась необходимость вычитывать файл бОльшими кусками (по 6 Кб), держать временный буфер такого размера жалко; поэтому, если решать задачу так же в лоб, можно вычитывать данные в основной буфер вместо временного, затем частями копировать во временный, переставляя элементы, затем опять копировать в основной. Но меня смущает необходимость двух копирований на каждый элемент массива (из основного во временный и обратно).
Хочу придумать перестановку без временного массива, с временной переменной, т.е, например, для числа 117
- копируем 0 элемент массива во временную переменную
- копируем 117 элемент в 0 элемент
- копируем значение временной переменной в 117 элемент ... и т.д.
Так получается 3 копирования на 2 элемента и в 2 раза меньшее количество итераций.
Но мозгов не хватает :( Буду благодарен, если кто-то подскажет примерный алгоритм.